# Combining two matrices of different size based on condition in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have two matrices, `A` of size 1x30974 and `B` of size 55x30974. Matrix `A` contains values from 1 to to 30974, while matrix `B` (first row) contains values that are also elements of matrix `A`, yet they do not have to be in order.

So in a simple case, I would have:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];
B = [1 2 6 8; 20 21 22 23; 30 31 32 33];
```

I would like to compare `A` and `B` in a way that my output would return:

```
C = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; 20 21 NaN NaN NaN 22 NaN 23; 30 31 NaN NaN NaN 32 NaN 33];
```

Saying differently, if the value in the first row of `B` is an element of `A`, then return all values in this column. If an element of A has no value in the first row of `B`, then the column is `NaN`.

In my case, the output would be of size 55x30974.

I guess that `ismember` could be the function I am looking for, but even then, how could I get the values of the column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use both outputs from [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html). The first tells you if a value is present and the second gives you the index where it is found (or `0` if it isn't present):

```
[isMatch, index] = ismember(B(1, :), A);
C = nan(size(B, 1), numel(A));
C(:, index(isMatch)) = B(:, isMatch);
```